# Picture doesn´t fit ImageButton

Tags: xamarin.forms, android-imagebutton

I want to write an app for Android with Xamarin.Forms and i want an ImageButton like in this question: [How to make a Floating Action Button in Xamarin Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54517874/how-to-make-a-floating-action-button-in-xamarin-forms)

The problem is as soon as i set the Background of the Button the Image is not displayed correctly. The Button is on the upper left corner of the Image and the Image is super big. The Button is shown correctly.

This is my Xaml with the Button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="ASUE.Views.ItemsPage"
             Title="AllItems"
             x:Name="BrowseItemsPage">

    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="Archive" Clicked="Archive_Clicked"/>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <AbsoluteLayout>
        <ScrollView AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1">
            <StackLayout>
                <ListView x:Name="ItemsListView"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                            HasUnevenRows="true"
                            RefreshCommand="{Binding LoadItemsCommand}"
                            IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true"
                            IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}"
                            CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
                            ItemSelected="OnItemSelected">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <StackLayout Padding="10" BackgroundColor="{Binding BColor, FallbackValue='White'}">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Title}"
                                            LineBreakMode="NoWrap" 
                                            Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" 
                                            FontSize="16" />
                                    <Label Text="{Binding ActionTime}" 
                                            LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
                                            Style="{DynamicResource ListItemDetailTextStyle}"
                                            FontSize="13" />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
        <ImageButton Source="add.png" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".95,.95,80,80" BackgroundColor="Transparent"/>
    </AbsoluteLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

I expect the Image to be the same size as the Button

**Update**

I tried [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJz2G.png)

```
<ImageButton Source="add.png"
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".1,.1,80,80"
BackgroundColor="Accent"
CornerRadius="80"/>
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUlCC.png)

```
<ImageButton Source="add.png"
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".1,.1,80,80"
BackgroundColor="Accent"
CornerRadius="80"
Padding="0,0,75,75"/>
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vx01.png)

```
<ImageButton Source="add.png"
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".1,.1,80,80"/>
```

[and This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfMFi.png)

```
<ImageButton Source="add.png"
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".1,.1,80,80"
CornerRadius="80"/>
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/imagebutton#imagebutton-appearance

Comment: The aspect property doesn't help or work proper. I've tried all three options

Comment: could you show your complete xaml ?

Comment: I have also tried it with different icons --> same problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `CornerRadius` to have a circle button. You also need to set the `Padding` property to make your image smaller:

```xml
<ImageButton Source="add.png" 
             AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" 
             AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".95,.95,80,80" 
             CornerRadius="80"
             Padding="15"
             BackgroundColor="Accent"/>
```

where add.png is:

[image]

You can get it here: https://material.io/resources/icons/?search=add&icon=add&style=baseline

in black or white

Comment: That helps a bit, the image gets smaler, but it isn't round anymore and don't fit in the shape of the button. My padding is like "0,0,75,75"

Comment: You don't have to use the trick where your image is a round image. With corner radius, you just have to use a regular image, which is a simple '+' and you can set the background color the way you want it.

Answer (score 0):

i just limit its width and height like this,is it the effect you want ?:

```
<ImageButton Source="add.png" 
             HorizontalOptions="Center"  
             VerticalOptions="Center"  
             CornerRadius="25" 
             WidthRequest="50" 
             HeightRequest="50"  
             AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"  
             AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".95,.95,80,80" 
             BackgroundColor="Accent"/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help but nothing of this works sadly.
So i just made a normal button with the picture as ImageSource and resized the picture correctly to fit the button.